# Control Podcasts in MacOS using Apple Watch

Tags: apple-watch, podcasts, remote.app

Is it possible to control the Podcasts app, running in MacOS, using Apple Watch?

I tried using the watch's Now Playing app, also to use the watch's Podcasts app, and the built-in Remote app, without any success.

It seems to me this feature of controlling audio with Apple Watch, is working only for the Music library, but [this Apple Discussions' issue](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252786492) points out that also Spotify tracks are working, so it's not limited to Apple Music.

Answer (score 1):

According to the  [Now Playing App description](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/now-playing/id1459548310), there’s no mention of Mac computers running macOS:

> The Now Playing app on Apple Watch will surface controls for content playing on your Apple Watch, iPhone or any of your connected devices like HomePod or paired Bluetooth speakers.

It’s important to remember that the Watch is an extension of the iPhone so the Now Playing App acts as a separate UI for the media playing on your iPhone.

Addaitionally, if you look under “Information” it will show the compatibility requirements:

> **Compatibility**
>
> - iPhone - Requires iOS 13.0 or later.
> - iPod touch - Requires iOS 13.0 or later.

There’s no mention of Mac computers or macOS.  So, this infers that it is controlling the app on device only and not the desktop.

As for Spotify, keep in mind that it is a *cloud* music service.  Now playing can control the app on the iPhone and if you’re signed into Spotify on a Mac as well, those activities will be mirrored.  There’s no evidence that Now Playing is controlling a desktop application from any of the discussions.

Comment: There are podcast apps that work with the watch, I believe. I gave up on Apple's podcast app years ago and now use Overcast. Not sure if it has controls on Apple Watch as I don't have one but I would suggest you look at third party podcast apps.

Comment: @Allan do you want to say, that the way Apple Watch controls Spotify, **including backward and forward of the currently playing soundtrack**, is mirrored very fast in real-time to the cloud, so every device will be updated with the "current minute/second" of playing of a specific song, for example? Instead of, to directly control the current-second of the song?

Comment: @Steve Chambers, actually Apple Podcasts is improving

Comment: @Cocktail - the feature you’re referring to is called  Spotify Connect.